# Filemerge application not working from svnX after installing xCode4.3?

Tags: iphone, xcode4, xcode4.3

I just installed xcode 4.3, since they moved filemerge application inside xCode package. filemerge is not working through svnX app(I have set default application as filemerge in svnX) to find the difference. How to fix this one(Xcode4.3 + svnX + filemerge)?

Comment: Just googled for your issue and found an interesting thread http://code.google.com/p/svnx/issues/detail?id=150 Check the two last messages there, it might be helpful (The suggested solution is to call a filemerge tool from within Xcode.app folder (that is not a file as you most probably know))

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It appears that the system does not know about the new path to the Developer directory. I executed the following command in Terminal and restarted svnX. This did the trick.

```
sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
```

Answer (score 0):

After installing the Xcode 4.3 all the utilities apps are moved in the Xcode.app folder in the applications. just do a "Show Package Contents" and navigate to : 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications and you'll find it there, u can drag it to your dock back again